# wp_insert_post hook not being called with wp_publish_post or wp_insert_post?

Tags: plugins, wp-insert-post, draft

I have a plugin that converts hashtags (any text that starts with #) into Wordpress tags. It's working great when I manually create a post via the Wordpress dashboard, but doesn't work when I programmatically create a post. Here's how I'm programmatically creating the posts:

First I create a draft:

```
$post = array(
  'post_content'   => $messagefordatabase,
  'post_name'      => $publickey,
  'post_title'     => $publickey,
  'post_status'    => 'draft'
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
```

Then when it's time to publish the post, this code changes the draft's publish status. (This publishes the post, but doesn't run the plugin):

```
wp_publish_post($postid);
```

And lastly, here's the code from the plugin:

```
function hashtags_insert_post( $id, $data ) {
  if (preg_match_all("/".HASHTAGS_REGEXP."/i", $data->post_content, $match)) {
    $tags = implode(", ", $match[2]);

    wp_add_post_tags( $data->post_parent, $tags );
  }

  return $id;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post', 'hashtags_insert_post', 99, 2 );
```

So in summary, the first 2 chunks of code above don't run the plugin. How can I trigger the plugin from either of those 2 chunks of code? Thanks!!

Comment: At which point during load are you creating the posts exactly?

Comment: The first piece of code above creates the post as a draft. Then the second piece of code changes the draft's status to published.

Comment: I understand what they do. But when and how do you run them? Is it in normal page? In Ajax request? In cron? On load? On init? After init?

Comment: The first 2 chunks are run from 2 separate page templates. Does that help? (Thanks for your help so far, btw!)

Comment: Hm... As described it should work then. Try to elaborate on details in the question.

Comment: `wp_publish_post()` bypasses filters, but there are some actions that are fired. Either use `wp_update_post()` to change your post status, or rather than attempting the filter hook that is not fired, use the action hook of the same name. I'm pretty sure that your function above will work just fine as is except there is no need to return anything if using the action hook.